# What would happen if earth was centre of the universe?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction

What would happen if earth was centre of the universe?

And everything in the solar system revolved around it.

Maybe the one like which ancient human believed
[image]

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is physically impossible. Are you asking how to make this possible, or what we might experience if we hand-wave the impossibility?

Comment: Being at the centre of the universe  (whatever that means) does not mean everything revolves around you.

Comment: @dunc123 ok i made the edit

Comment: Ignoring everything else in the solar system for a second, the sun wouldn't  revolve around the earth. Two bodies revolve around their common centre of mass. In the case of the earth and the sun, they rotate around some point near the middle of the sun.

Comment: Anybody else feel that this is too broad?

Comment: If you look out into the Universe in any direction, you will find that it ends at precisely the same distance away in every direction, as we are limited to seeing light that is at a maximum 13.8 billion years old. The distance we can see is actually further that 13.8 billion lightyears thanks to the Universe expanding, but my point remains the same - we are each the centre of our own Universe, and nothing could possibly prove that wrong :)

Comment: What do you mean by *if it was*?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Could a planet be the center...](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/42380/6986).

Comment: @AlexClough This question seems to me to be a lot of things, broad being one of those things. (Vishnu JK; "what would happen if X?" questions are almost always too broad. Ask instead about some *specific* aspect of the world.) I'm not sure the one that Frostfyre linked to is an *exact* duplicate, but it does seem close enough to provide a good understanding that will lead to an answer to this question. (Specifically, that question asking *whether it is possible* while this asks *what would happen*. I do think the answers very much apply to this question too, though.)

Comment: Your image is of ptolemaic geocentrism, which is simply not possible, but tychonean geocentrism is not only perfectly possible but even likely, and guess what? It would look exactly the same. The only factor influencing the interpretation is the Cosmological Principle, which is the assumption that the universe is homogeneous.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: nothing you have proposed is possible.

Let's start with the other objects in the solar system orbiting the Earth.

Here's the biggest problem: **things with *less* mass orbit things with *more* mass**.

How much mass does the Earth have? Let's compare it to the other planets and some stars.

[image: Sizes]

Very, very, *very* little.

So let's make the Earth bigger/give it more mass. Enough mass to have a significant sphere of gravitational influence and enough to host our sun. First we bump the size up to that of Jupiter's. At this point the gravity would be *crushing*. Now let's make it 13x bigger. At this point, you don't even have a planet anymore, you have a brown dwarf. It has so much mass that thermonuclear fusion briefly occurred at its core. Make it much bigger and it will continue to burn. You'll have a bona fide **star**.

If Earth's influence on the Solar System is *relatively insignificant*, on the cosmic level Earth is *absolutely 110% entirely insignificant and isn't even worth mentioning*. You can't compare it to a speck of dust. You can't compare it to an atom. It's so small our tiny brains can't even comprehend just how small it is.

As for the center of the universe: congratulations, in a way you're at it right now.

**There isn't one.**

If the universe is finite, space is curved. If you went forward long enough, you'd return to the exact same place you started.

If the universe is infinite, well, then it definitely doesn't have a center.

The universe is expanding, yes. But it's not expanding from a single point. It's expanding from *every* point (this doesn't tear apart things that are bound together by gravity, though).

Comment: Excellent graphic that displays your point well.

Comment: This is just plain wrong. Bodies orbit the center of mass of a system, not other bodies. There's nothing but assumptions of mediocrity preventing the center of mass of the whole universe being where the Earth is. It wouldn't look like the Ptolemaic geocentrism in the OP picture, but it's not impossible.